# NullPointerException : Cannot send from MessageListener to client via websocket with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, redis

I am trying to send message to topic `/topic/room`, after subscribed message from Redis.
My code is following.

```
@Component
public class RedisSubscriber implements MessageListener {

    static private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RedisSubscriber.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(final Message message, final byte[] pattern) {

        log.info("template: " + template);
        template.convertAndSend("/topic/room", message);
        log.info("Message send: " + message.toString());
    }
}
```

Result is following.
I don't know why `SimpMessagingTemplate` object is null.
It seems SimpMessagingTemplate is not `@Autowired`.
Do I need to create other template or not?
Please advise to me.

Got following exception

```
2017-07-12 19:53:24.920  INFO 8724 --- [edisContainer-2] j.c.t.l.delivery.redis.RedisSubscriber   : template: null
2017-07-12 19:53:24.939 ERROR 8724 --- [edisContainer-2] o.s.d.r.l.a.MessageListenerAdapter       : Listener execution failed

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at XXXX.redis.RedisSubscriber.onMessage(RedisSubscriber.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:299) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:249) [spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer.processMessage(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:239) [spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer$1.run(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:967) [spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Addtional infomation is following.
This is how I obtain `RedisSubscriber` to register it with `MessageListenerAdapter`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(new RedisSubscriber());
    }

    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer() {
        final RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();

        container.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        container.addMessageListener(messageListener(), topic());

        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    RedisPublisher redisPublisher() {
        return new RedisPublisher(redisTemplate(), topic());
    }

    @Bean
    ChannelTopic topic() {
        return new ChannelTopic("topic");
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically in Spring an `@Autowired` field can/will never be `null` unless you are creating new instances yourself outside the scope of Spring. If spring cannot auto wire fields it will fail to startup. Also there is no line `27` in the code you show here.

Comment: Can you post the code how you obtain `RedisSubscriber` to register it with `MessageListenerAdapter`? Looks like you're instantiating it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

In AppConfig you can auto-wire your subscriber

```java
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowire
    RedisSubscriber redisSubscriber

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(redisSubscriber);
    }
}
```

And if your Subscriber is annotated with @Service you can auto-wire services inside the subscriber class:

```java
@Service
public class RedisSubscriber implements MessageListener {
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template // should be non-null
}
```

Comment: Perfectly worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

The problem had been resolved.
Now it is working with following code.
I did state `SimpMessagingTemplate` on `AppConfig` class instead of `RedisSubscriber` class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired                                  <- Add
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;     <- Add
```

and

```
public class RedisSubscriber implements MessageListener {

    static private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RedisSubscriber.class.getName());
    private final SimpMessagingTemplate template;                                        <- Add

    public RedisSubscriber(final SimpMessagingTemplate template) {                        <- Add
        this.template = template;                                                         <- Add
    }                                                                                     <- Add

    @Override
    public void onMessage(final Message message, final byte[] pattern) {
```

Thank you for advises.

Comment: Where you have added a default constructor  in RedisSubscriber